# Tailwind space-x-# does not apply any styles

Tags: tailwind-css

I have the following:

```
<div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-start flex-nowrap space-x-6">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
</div>
```

Now the there is no space-x-6 applied between the items. However when I try this in the Tailwind playground it works. Any ideas?

tailwind.config.js:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: {
        blob: 'blob 7s infinite',
      },
      keyframes: {
        blob: {
          '0%': {
            transform: 'translate(0px, 0px) scale(1)',
          },
          '33%': {
            transform: 'translate(30px, -50px) scale(1.1)',
          },
          '66%': {
            transform: 'translate(-20px, 20px) scale(0.9)',
          },
          '100%': {
            transform: 'tranlate(0px, 0px) scale(1)',
          },
        },
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        mono: ['iAWriter Mono', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.mono],
      },
      boxShadow: {
        card: '0 0 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075)',
      },
      typography: (theme) => ({
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
            figcaption: {
              textAlign: 'center',
            },
            strong: {
              fontWeight: theme('fontWeight.medium'),
            },
            // Image margin is handled by `figure`
            img: {
              marginTop: null,
              marginBottom: null,
              borderRadius: theme('borderRadius.lg'),
            },
            blockquote: {
              borderLeftWidth: '2px',
              fontStyle: null,
              fontWeight: theme('fontWeight.normal'),
              borderColor: theme('colors.blue.600'),
            },
            hr: {
              borderTopWidth: '2px',
              maxWidth: '12rem',
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              marginRight: 'auto',
            },
            'blockquote p:first-of-type::before, blockquote p:last-of-type::after': {
              content: 'unset !important',
            },
            a: {
              color: theme('colors.blue.600'),
              wordWrap: 'break-word',
              fontWeight: theme('fontWeight.normal'),
              textDecoration: 'none',
              textUnderlineOffset: '0.2em',
              '&:hover': {
                textDecoration: 'underline',
              },
            },
            'ol > li::before': {
              fontFamily: theme('fontFamily.mono').join(', '),
              color: theme('colors.gray.400'),
            },
            'ul > li::before': {
              backgroundColor: theme('colors.gray.400'),
            },
            '.twitter-tweet': {
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              marginRight: 'auto',
            },
            code: {
              fontWeight: theme('fontWeight.normal'),
              background: theme('colors.gray.200'),
              color: theme('colors.gray.600'),
              borderRadius: theme('borderRadius.lg'),
              padding: `0.125rem ${theme('padding.1')}`,
              '&::before, &::after': {
                content: 'unset !important',
              },
            },
            '[data-nft] *, .opengraph *, .opengraph *:hover': {
              margin: '0',
              textDecoration: 'none',
              borderRadius: 'unset',
            },
          },
        },
        lg: {
          css: {
            'ol > li, ul > li': {
              marginTop: '0',
              marginBottom: '0',
            },
            // Image margin is handled by `figure`
            img: {
              marginTop: null,
              marginBottom: null,
            },
          },
        },
      }),
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography'), require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'), require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

UPDATE:
So for the space-x-# class I do a little fancyness:

```
export function getSpacing(spacing, direction) {
  const spacingTailwindClasses = [];

  if (typeof direction === 'string') {
    spacingTailwindClasses.push(getTailwindSpacingClassname(spacing, direction));
  } else {
    spacingTailwindClasses.push(getTailwindSpacingClassname(spacing, direction.sOnly || direction.sUp));
    if (direction.sUp) {
      spacingTailwindClasses.push(`sm:${getTailwindSpacingClassname(spacing, direction.sUp)}`);
      if (direction.sOnly) {
        spacingTailwindClasses.push(`sm:${getTailwindSpacingClassname('none', direction.sOnly)}`);
      }
    }
  }

  const spacingObject = {};
  const classes = spacingTailwindClasses.join(' ');
  spacingObject[classes] = true;

  return spacingObject;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove your cache and restart dev server, in my case in NextJS i had to remove `.next` cache folder and restart it if some new styles were not picked up.

Comment: No didnt fix it. I found the cause but dont know why actually. Check at the end of my question where I wrote UPDATE

Comment: For some reason join could be the issue but i dont know why

Comment: and if you try `const classes = ['space-x-6'].join(' ')` ? I think it may be that the `spacingTailwindClasses` is in some context in which tailwind is not finding the specific string `space-x-6`.

Comment: That does work. I posted the full function I have to get the spacing in the original question. spacingTailwindClasses is within the same function. If i do `spacingObject[['space-x-6'].join(' ')] = true;` it works fine

Comment: Somewhere in tailwind documentation (couldnt find it right now) there is mentioned not to create classes dynamically by concatenating strings or using variables for part of class name because they will be purged since tailwind does not see the final string in your code. If you insist on creating classes like this use `safelist` in tailwind config, check https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Comment: Ah I see thats probably it then, thanks!

Comment: yep `pattern: /space-(x|y)-(0|0.5|1.5|3|4|6)/,` did the trick for the safelist